# Artificial Intelligence trends and topics

Tags: data-science-model, ai

I was wondering if there are websites with which to stay constantly updated on the latest trends or topics on disruptive applications in artificial intelligence.

I usually read scientific publications subject to university research, but I was wondering where to read applications, innovative and disruptive use cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few that I can recommend:

- [MIT News on Machine Learning](https://news.mit.edu/topic/machine-learning)
- [AI Weekly Newsletter](https://aiweekly.co/)
- Pretty new site, but found some interesting articles there already: [Data Basecamp](https://databasecamp.de/en/homepage)
- [Scientific Papers](https://www.nature.com/subjects/machine-learning)